# Global convergence behavior of several Krylov solvers in scipy.opt

Tags: nonlinear-equations, scipy, krylov-method

In the context of mechanical simulation, where I solve the stationary action principle directly (i.e. $\nabla S = 0$ for some scalar function $S$), I use the wrapper `scipy.optimize.newton_krylov` to access several different nonlinear Krylov based solvers (in particular, `lgmres` and `cgs`).

The equations have many solutions, and different initial guesses will return different solutions. This is to be expected.
In order to find multiple solutions, I initialize the initial guess using a random number generator, and then call `scipy.optimize.newton_krylov`.

My observation is the following: the two solvers `lgmres` and `cgs` tend to converge towards qualitatively different solutions. In a sense, the solutions found by `cgs` are nicer and simpler while those found by `lgmres` are more complex and convoluted.

My question(s): Is there an explanation for this situation? Is it possible that the dynamics of the `cgs` solver are unstable around the most complex solutions, and why? Do the basins of convergence of the two methods have qualitatively different properties? And finally, is it possible to link this behavior to the spectrum of the Hessian of $S$ at the solution?

Comment: What happens if you feed save the initial guess from one and use it with the other?

Comment: This is a good point. I'm going to try that, possibly  with a small random perturbation to see if there is some kind of stability or not

Comment: "nicer", "simpler", "complex", and "convoluted" are the wrong adjectives. The question is whether the solution found by the solver is "correct" or "wrong". If you don't know which one is correct, you're looking at too complicated a test case. Pick something for which you know the exact solution.

Comment: Do the solutions that you get with cgs have smaller norm than the lgmres solutions?

Comment: @Brian : thanks for the tip, I'll try this test.

Comment: @Wolfgang : all the solutions are correct. The norm of the residuals is always less than $10^{-12}$

Comment: After tests : I can confidently say that some converged solutions found by lgmres, after being only slightly perturbed, will NOT be found by cgs. Those seem to be somehow repelling points of cgs, whilst they are attractive for lgmres. I could not find any solution where the roles are switched (repelling for lgmres, attractive for cgs).

Comment: And no, I could not find any eidence that the solutions with cgs have a smaller norm that the lgmres solutions.

Comment: Do you have any ideas or links on ways of plotting trajectories in high dimensions, static plots or, better, movies ? (a soft question)

Comment: @denis : I'm not sure I understand your questions. My trajectories are not "high" dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Try [bicgstab](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.bicgstab.html), not cgs. 
Be careful with `tol` and `atol`; what values did you use ?

[SVD](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html)
of your various solutions, matrices say `Xres` and `Xcg`
might help see their similarities and differences;
tiny singular values
$\Rightarrow$ ill-conditioning or large nullspace.

(Not your question, but a simple testcase for linear solvers is $poisson2() - 4.0001 \,  I$,
$N^2 \times N^2$ with $N$ eigenvalues at $-0.0001$, $b$ a point source.
Scipy lgmres and bicgstab do $N=100$ ok, cgs and tfqmr are terrible.)

---

Added: To my surprise, scipy Newton-Krylov lgmres is not just
a Newton stepper $\leftrightarrow$ an iterative solver;
instead, it couples them more tightly.
[_nonlin.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/_nonlin.py) --

```
1316 class KrylovJacobian(Jacobian):
1434         elif self.method is scipy.sparse.linalg.lgmres:
1436             # Replace LGMRES's outer iteration with Newton steps
1437             self.method_kw['maxiter'] = 1
1438             # Carry LGMRES's `outer_v` vectors across nonlinear iterations
```

This is clever, I guess good for some problems -- but which ?

Comment: *Use bicgstab, not cgs.* I suggest to explain why.

Comment: @Federico Poloni, see the last line: cgs explodes on that testcase, bicgstab and lgmres work fine. Of course, method xx may or may not work on the OP's problem; I'll change "use" to 'try".

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, your point is the following : The convergence process using cgs is locally bad for some points where the corresponding linear problem is not well handled by cgs. Is this correct ?

Comment: In particular, my tangent problem has a (small) nullspace (and thus 0 eigenvalues). But still, cgs finds **some** solutions and not others.

Comment: @G. Fougeron, yes, cgs is bad on large-nullspace $A$.
The outer newton-krylov calls a linear solver with many different $A$,
how do you know if they're all ok --
can you save them / post them ?
(Also, did the suggestion on SVD make sense ?)

Comment: Yes, SVD makes a lot of sense to investigate the eigenstructure of the matrix, although in my particular case, I have symmetric matrices so SVD and eigendecomposition coincide.

Comment: ", how do you know if they're all ok -- can you save them / post them ? " ==> What do you mean ? Yes I can save solutions. I've gathered a few at this address : https://gabrielfougeron.github.io//gallery/